# Heap in function overlaps function parameter

Tags: c, malloc

I wrote a program which merge output directory name (`argv[1]`) with file name (`char *output_files_basename[]`):

**algo.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include "algo.h"
#include "parameters.h"

char *output_files_basename[] = {
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3",
    "test4",
    NULL
};

extern int errno;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char output_dir[MAX_PATH_LENGTH] = "";
    char *output_files_fullpath[] = { NULL };
    int ret = 0;

    /* check parameters */
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Not enough parameters\n");
        printf("Should be:\n");
        printf("%s output_dir\n", argv[0]);
        return EINVAL;
    }

#if DEBUG > 0
    printf("Arguments: \n");
    printf("output_dir: %s\n", argv[1]);
#endif

    strncpy(output_dir, argv[1], MAX_PATH_LENGTH - 1);
    output_dir[MAX_PATH_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';

#if DEBUG > 0
    printf("output_dir: %s\n", output_dir);
#endif

    /* set full input file names */
    form_fullpath(output_files_fullpath, output_files_basename, output_dir);

    free_fullpath(output_files_fullpath);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**algo.h**:

```
#ifndef ALGO_H
#define ALGO_H

#define DEBUG           1

#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 256

#endif /* ALGO_H */
```

**parameters.h**:

```
#ifndef PARAMETERS_H
#define PARAMETERS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "algo.h"

/* get input_dir and append to input_files_basename => input_files_fullpath */
void form_fullpath(char *input_files_fullpath[], char *input_files_basename[], char *input_dir);

/* free memory */
void free_fullpath(char *input_files_fullpath[]);

#endif /* PARAMETERS_H */
```

**parameters.c**:

```
#include "parameters.h"

extern int errno;

void form_fullpath(char *input_files_fullpath[], char *input_files_basename[], char *input_dir) {

    int file_iter = 0;
    char *strtmp = NULL;

    for (file_iter = 0; input_files_basename[file_iter] != NULL && input_dir != NULL; file_iter++) {
        //#ifdef TTT
        input_files_fullpath[file_iter] = malloc(sizeof(char) *
                          (strlen(input_files_basename[file_iter]) +
                           strlen(input_dir) + 2) /* '/' and '\0' */);
        //#endif
        /*sprintf(input_files_fullpath[file_iter], "%s/%s%c",
                  input_dir,
                  input_files_basename[file_iter],
                  '\0');*/

#if DEBUG > 0
        //printf("file_fullpath[%d]: %s\n", file_iter, input_files_fullpath[file_iter]);
        printf("input_files_basename[%d]: %s\n", file_iter, input_files_basename[file_iter]);
        printf("%d input_dir: %s\n", file_iter, input_dir);
#endif
    }
    input_files_fullpath[file_iter] = NULL;
}

void free_fullpath(char *input_files_fullpath[]) {
    int file_iter = 0;

    for (file_iter = 0; input_files_fullpath[file_iter] != NULL; file_iter++) {
        free(input_files_fullpath[file_iter]);
    }
}
```

When I comment `malloc` in `form_fullpath` function I have this output:

```
./algo output/
Arguments:
output_dir: output/
output_dir: output/
input_files_basename[0]: test1
0 input_dir: output/
input_files_basename[1]: test2
1 input_dir: output/
input_files_basename[2]: test3
2 input_dir: output/
input_files_basename[3]: test4
3 input_dir: output/
```

But when I uncomment `malloc` in `form_fullpath` function I have output like this:

```
./algo output/
Arguments:
output_dir: output/
output_dir: output/
input_files_basename[0]: test1
0 input_dir: output/
input_files_basename[1]: test2
1 input_dir: P
input_files_basename[2]: test3
2 input_dir: P
input_files_basename[3]: test4
3 input_dir: P
```

Why does `malloc` overlap `input_dir` function parameter? I'll be thankful if anyone can explain me.

Comment: `char *output_files_fullpath[] = {NULL};` how many elements does `output_files_fullpath` have? How many do you try to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why malloc overlaps input_dir function parameter?

Because your code is invalid. The array:

```
char *output_files_fullpath[] = {NULL};
```

has only one element, yet you write out-of-bounds to it in `form_fullpath`, in pseudocode:

```
int main() {
     char *output_files_fullpath[] = {NULL};
     form_fullpath(output_files_fullpath, ...)
}
void form_fullpath(char *input_files_fullpath[],  ...) {
   for (file_iter in 0 1 2 3) {
      input_files_fullpath[file_iter] = something
   }
}
```

`input_files_fullpath` has only 1 element, not 5. You can:

- Allocate more elements `char *output_files_fullpath[20];`
- use dynamic allocation to dynamically re-allocate `output_files_fullpath` each loop, for example.

Notes:

- Instead of `malloc+snprintf` you could use `asprintf`.`
- Doing `sprintf(..., "%c", '\0')` is pointless, results in writing *two* zeros on the end of string and I think this is also a bug as it results in writing to the memory out-of-bounds by byte. Remove that `'\0'`. `sprintf` always writes zero terminating character by itself anyway.
- Prefer to use `snprintf`.
- I guess, consider using shorter variable names? It's kind of strange that `output_files_fullpath` becomes `input_files_fullpath` in function, it's still output.
- Consider using `size_t` for array iterators.

Comment: Thank you. I really wasn't to much closer with array of pointers. Your explanation is really help me. I've just removed termination zero from array of pointers and use snprintf instead of sprintf.